# Cant add markers from array through for loop

Tags: google-maps, loops, google-maps-markers

```
var lats = ["56.1581702","56.1580875","56.1588094","56.1510389","56.15943499999999","56.1576479"];
var lons = ["13.767593300000044","13.752623399999948","13.764544","13.768728699999997","13.768018600000005","13.76731380000001"];
var i = 0;
var image = '/bilder/location.png';
for(lats.length > i) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i], lons[i]),
            icon: image
        });
 var i++;
}
```

Cant get this code to work, only a blank map is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop expression is invalid. Try this :

```
var lats = ["56.1581702","56.1580875","56.1588094","56.1510389","56.15943499999999","56.1576479"];
var lons = ["13.767593300000044","13.752623399999948","13.764544","13.768728699999997","13.768018600000005","13.76731380000001"];
var image = '/bilder/location.png';
for(var i = 0; i < lats.length; ++i) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i], lons[i]),
        icon: image
    });
}
```

The developer tools available in modern browsers will help you to debug syntax errors in your code.